# Webpack Dev Server cannot find modules with Typescript if I use custom paths in tsconfig

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack

I'm building a project from scratch on React + TypeScript and using the Webpack Dev server.
I want to use relative paths to components, which will be not strict for a more flexible development.

In my App.tsx, I'm trying to import component:

```
import EntityTypes from "components/EntityTypes/EntityTypes";
```

and getting an error

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'components/EntityTypes/EntityTypes' in '/home/eugene/prj/work/crud-react/src'
```

File by this path exists (/src/components/EntityTypes/EntityTypes.js) and exports the class like

```
export default EntityTypes;
```

My tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "es2015",
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ],
    "removeComments": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": false,
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowJs": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "components/*": [
        "src/components/*"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js:

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require( 'html-webpack-plugin' );
const path = require( 'path' );
module.exports = {
    context: __dirname,
    entry: './src/index.js',
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve( __dirname, 'dist' ),
        filename: 'main.js',
        publicPath: '/',
    },
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(tsx|ts)?$/,
                loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                use: 'babel-loader',
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|j?g|svg|gif)?$/,
                use: 'file-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
            template: path.resolve( __dirname, 'public/index.html' ),
            filename: 'index.html'
        })
    ]
};
```

I've checked the documentation of typescript about "paths", the file is exists, I don't understand what the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have sorted out how to use paths for my files and make them flexible, that I can reorganize the project and manage paths easy without a lot of changes of strict relative paths.

The problem was related to configuration of the webpack.
Final configuration is next:

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // ...
    "paths": {
      "~/components/*": [
        "./src/components/*"
      ],
      "~/services/*": [
        "./src/services/*"
      ],
      "~/interfaces/*": [
        "./src/interfaces/*"
      ]
    },
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  // ...
  resolve: {
    // ...
    alias: {
      '~/components': path.resolve(process.cwd(), './src/components'),
      '~/interfaces': path.resolve(process.cwd(), './src/interfaces'),
      '~/services': path.resolve(process.cwd(), './src/services'),
    }
  },
}
```

**Examples of usage**

```
import {IEntities} from "~/interfaces/entities.interface";
// ...
import EntityForm from "~/components/EntityForm/EntityForm";
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin` into your webpack configuration:

```js
const { cwd } = require('node:process');
const { resolve } = require('node:path');

const TsconfigPathsWebpackPlugin = require('tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin');


module.exports = {
    resolve: {
        plugins: [
            new TsconfigPathsWebpackPlugin({
                configFile: resolve(cwd(), './tsconfig.json'),
            })
        ]
    }

};
```

And you don't need to duplicate paths configuration as webpack aliases.

Answer (score -2):

You're using absolute imports, not relative ones. Try `import EntityTypes from "./components/EntityTypes/EntityTypes";`, assuming the file you're importing it into is on the same level as the `components` directory.

Comment: If I will do so, it means that it's just a relative import of the file? What the sense of config in this case? 
My goal is that I can change the structure of the project, move some folders, but do not edit import in each file, but just update paths in tsconfig.json. Can I acheive it how I described in initial post?