# Why am I getting a Module Not Found error from TypeScript for PNG files even after defining a PNG type?

Tags: typescript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, typescript-typings, phaser-framework

I'm trying to create a game in HTML, and I decided to use Phaser 3 along with Webpack and Typescript to allow for modern practices. I'm now trying to import a PNG file to use with Phaser but Typescript keeps throwing up a `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'assets/tower-base.png'` when I'm trying to run webpack-dev-server. I've spent a while reading google results but all I've found is you need to define a custom typing for png files, which I've done. This seems to have resolved most peoples problems but doesn't seem to be working for me and I have no idea what to try next. I'm hoping you kind folks can point out to me where I'm going wrong and why.

In my Phaser Scene I am trying to import the image. Here is my Scene file:

### SingleScene.ts

```js
import * as Phaser from 'phaser';
import TowerBase from 'assets/tower-base.png';

export default class SingleScene extends Phaser.Scene {
    constructor() {
        super('single-scene');
    }

    preload() {
        this.load.image('towerBase', TowerBase);
    }

    create() {
    }
}
```

The error specifically happens on line 2. So after googling the issue I find out I need a custom typing definition for PNG files. In the root of my project I added a `custom-typings.d.ts` file containing only the definition for PNG files.

### custom-typings.d.ts

```js
declare module "*.png" {
    const value: any;
    export default value;
}
```

And then I referenced this file in my `tsconfig.json` file under `typeRoots`. This is my complete config file for completeness

### tsconfig.json

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./dist/",
        "module": "es6",
        "target": "es5",
        "allowJs": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ],
    "typeRoots": [
        "./custom-typings.d.ts",
        "./node_modules/phaser/types"
    ],
    "types": [
        "Phaser"
    ]
}
```

I have made sure to have a rule in my webpack config for images as well. This is the module rules part of my webpack config file:

### webpack.config.js

```js
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.tsx$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
        },
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            use: ['source-map-loader'],
            enforce: 'pre',
        },
        {
            test: /\.s[ac]ss$/,
            use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
        },
        {
            test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
            use: {
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    outputPath: 'assets',
                },
            },
        },
    ],
},
```

As far as I can tell from googling the issue everything is as it should be, but clearly I'm missing something or it would be working. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be referencing an absolute path here. Does it work if you instead:

```js
import TowerBase from './assets/tower-base.png';
```

If so, and if you instead want to use absolute paths, you'll need to set up a path mapping in your `tsconfig.json` like so:

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "assets/*": ["./assets/*"]
    }
}
```

You can find more information at https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping

Comment: Nope, using `'./assets/tower-base.png'` makes no difference, I get the same error. In fact, that path isn't valid because the js file is in `/src/js/SingleScene.ts` and the image is in `/src/assets/tower-base.png`, so it would have to be `./../assets/tower-base.png`, which works! Why?!

Comment: Also, I tried to set up a path so that I could use `assets/tower-base.png` but it doesn't work. I've tried ```"baseUrl": ".", "paths": { "assets/": ["./src/assets/*"] }```.

Comment: Ah, OK, figured out the problem with path mapping, you need to config the aliases in webpack as well. I got that bit working from here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58443646/webpack-dev-server-cannot-find-modules-with-typescript-if-i-use-custom-paths-in